# Multiple types for a field in Graphene

Tags: graphene-python

I have the following class

```
class Input(InputObjectType):
    feature: Graphene.String = Graphene.String()
    value: ??
```

Where `value` can represent all primitive types (int, float, bool, string).
Is there a way to represent it in Graphene

Thanks!